# Distribution of the difference between two random variables

Tags: random-variables, gamma-distribution

I have two independent random variables of Erlang distribution or you can consider them Gamma distributions but they are positive. Z = Y-X

The difference between them should be a distribution that represents a time period. Physically it can be only more than or equal to zero.

Is it safe to ignore the part where Z<0 ?

Comment: The answer depends entirely on the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$. Your model should incorporate the fact the $Y-X$ cannot be negative, and if it doesn't, it's insufficient to describe what you're asking for it. Simply ignoring the negative part will most likely give you errors when trying to apply this in any context.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 thank you for your prompt comment. Z can be negative  but I can not wrap my head around how can I get a time period in negative!!. The distribution was a result of a markov model for network delay.

Comment: Essentially, simply given the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$, no conclusion about $Z$ can be made. If your model requires that $Z>0$, then the **joint distribution** of $X$ and $Y$ should be something that ensures that. If you don't know the joint distribution, you're lost when trying to, say, determine the distribution of $Z$, or (in this case) even a condition on it.

Comment: sorry for the naive questions, I am new in the probability distribution. Can't I simply assume that for $X$ > $Y$ $Z=0$ ? I have got a closed from for $$Z>0$$ similar to http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/48424.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $Z$ is positive should depend on your hypothesis on $Y$ and $X$. If you do not suppose that $\mathbb{P}(Y \geqslant X) = 1$ (you only suppose that they are independent) then you cannot suppose at the same time that $Y - X$ is positive.